# Session state variable throwing exception on being used. How to resolve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if a Session state variable is null or no. If it is not null there is a function to be used. However this is throwing an exception.

When `Session["Set_Parameters]` is null it is throwing an exception. I need it to avoid the if statement if it is null.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Set_Parameters"].ToString()))
        {
            Edit_String();
        }
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get returned null.

This is the exception I am getting.

Answer (score -2):

Problem with your code is you're trying to convert a null value to string, then test that for null or empty.

Try this...

```
If (Session["Set_Parameters"] != null) {
  ...
}
```